# Simpler way to compare list items to a string?

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is what I'm doing:

```
list = ["item", "item2", "item3"]
list2 = ["other", "stuff"]
string = "this is a string"
for item in list:
    if string.startswith(item):
       for item in list2:
           if item in string:
               <do stuff>
```

and was wondering if there was a simpler way to do that.

Comment: Simpler how? That looks to be the correct way of doing things, it's clear and readable.

Comment: It's unlikely to be a good idea to reassign to `list` like that.

Comment: It just seemed like a long way of doing things. Was just hoping something like: 
    if string.startswith(any item in list) and (any item in list) in string:

         #do stuff, existed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment you want this:

```
if string.startswith(tuple(item)):
    if any(item in string for item in list2):
        do stuff
```

But this is something different than that, what your posted code does. `<do stuff>` is executed only once, whereas in your code it can be executed many times.

Comment: I should clarify, I actually had a break in do stuff so it only executed once anyway. I think this might be what I was looking for. Thanks.